# InvalidArgumentError: Default MaxPooling Op only supports NHWC

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, image-classification

I am trying to perform Image classification on binary images which are grey scale images and I am receiving an error **"Default MaxPoolingOp only supports NHWC on device type CPU"**.
I saw answers for similar questions posted in Stack and tried to reshape my X_train and my input passed
X_train shape is `(10000, 64,64,1)`
input_shape = `(64,64,1)`

When I execute the below line for defining the input shape, I get Error:

```
"Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node conv2d_29/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT,data_format="NCHW", dilations = [1,1,1,1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID"....."
```

Line executed :

```
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(2,2), input_shape = (64,64,1)))
```

@Nicolas Gervais

Comment: Can you include some code, e.g., your model architecture?

Comment: Hi Nicolas, Thanks for your reply. I am working out with the example in the Kaggle link : kaggle.com/damienpark/image-classification-using-cnn. Its the same data and code in the link but with input shape and x_trani shape changed to NHWC

Comment: @SMP, Is your issue resolved now? Else, can you try to add  `padding="SAME"` to your `Conv2D` layer. Thanks!